# Access-Control-Allow-Origin - Error when trying to access JSON from Wordpress installation

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cors

I try to access my blog using the "old" Json-Api from JavaScript (AngularJS)

Now I receive the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://example.com/?json=get_category_index. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Looks like a simple thing. But even after I tried the following:

Add these lines into the .htaccess:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Add the following line to the themes' header.php and to json-api.php:

```
<? header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>
```

I still get this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `JSONP` in AngularJS.

`JSONP` is used to request data from a server in a different domain.

Documented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp).

Comment: Even if the main problem was different (my own answer) I like this one even more, cause it does a more clean solution.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. Solved it. Was a bit tricky:

I had to change ">`<? xxx ?>`" to "`<?php xxx ?>`"

The "`<?`" - part was not rendered as server-code but was output like normal html.

Answer (score 1):

The remote server that you're trying to access (JSON) is the one that should allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin, not your Wordpress host.

If they're in the same server, then it could be that you forgot to set relative URLs, so when trying from localhost you won't be able to access your web host.

Comment: You misunderstood. I read the data from my blog (example.com)